Web3 & Paymaster: How can I call a smart contract with web3js and make a paymaster pay for the gas fees?
I am looking for an approach to call a smart contract function via web3js in angular 17.
The gas fees should be paied by a paymaster-contract.
How can I achieve this?
web3-version: 4.6.0
angular-Version: 17
network: zkSync
      const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
      const nftContract = await new web3.eth.Contract(environment.nftTokenAbi, tokenAddress);
      const data = nftContract.methods.mint(address).encodeABI();

      const transactionParameters = {
        to: tokenAddress,
        from: senderAddress,
        data,
      };

      const txHash = await web3.eth.sendTransaction(transactionParameters);

I already tried to use @opengsn/provider and set the given RelayProvider to Web3-Constructor.
But this didnt worked so far because the RelayProvider-Class could not be found.

I would first make sure you've followed the "Getting Started" on GSN's docs, either for v2.2.5 or for v3.0.0-beta.
If you are getting an error saying the RelayProvider could not be found, maybe you forgot to install it?
npm install --save @opengsn/provider

You can find a step-by-step working project in their workshop repo (the changes are in 3 different branches, or in the PRs, not in main): https://github.com/opengsn/workshop
Otherwise, you might want to look at ERC-4337, even thought I think zkSync supports account abstraction and Paymasters natively, so you might not even need GSN nor ERC-4337.
